# Insert javascript variable between string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#did').html('<input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="Save" onClick="saveContent('+valA+')">');
function saveContent(con){
 alert (con);
}
</script>
```

*I am using this code to display a submit button and it comes to the page body. but when clicked on the button it is not alerting the value. Please help me... 
Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

Why `type="submit"`?

assuming `#did` is the `id` of your div or some container

```
$("#did").html($("<input type='button' value='save' />").click(function(){
    alert(valA);
}));
```

This will append a button in your div with click event attached to it. Remember type should be button for this case.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. It is working now... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Escape insert variable

Your result is:

```
<input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="Save" onClick="saveContent(sometext)">
```

**Error** : `sometext is not defined`

```
$('#did').html('<input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="Save" onClick="saveContent(\''+valA+'\')">');
function saveContent(con){
 alert (con);
}
```

Result of this:

```
<input type="submit" name="mybtn" value="Save" onClick="saveContent('sometext')">
```

**but use better previous answer**

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. It is working now... :-)